# How to invoke a js from link_to in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to invoke a js.erb from my `link_to`

I tried this:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr><td>
    <%= link_to category, :controller => "movies", :action => "show_category", :category => category, :method => :post, :remote => true%>    
  </td></tr>
<% end %>
```

This is my complete `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: "movies#index"

  post '/movies/show_category', to: 'movies#show_category', as: 'show_movies_by_category'
end
```

This is my target function in `movies_controller` I would like to be called when the `link_to` is clicked (my understanding is from this function, I could invoke `show_category.js.erb` Javascript file):

```
def show_category
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end
```

But instead of calling `movies_controller#show_category`, `movies_controller#show` seems to be invoked. This is what I see in my Rails console:

```
Started GET "/movies/show_category?category=Romance&method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-06 13:41:47 +0530
Processing by MoviesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"category"=>"Romance", "method"=>"post", "id"=>"show_category"}
  Movie Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:87
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=show_category):

app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:87:in `set_movie'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you posted the whole routes.rb file here if you can.

Comment: @art-solopov sure. I have updated my question with the complete contents from my `routes.rb`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with routing. Your `"/movies/show_category/<...>"` request is being parsed as `movies/:id`, with the `id` parameter being set to `show_category`.

Since your `movies` routes is defined as a resource route (`resources movies`), then the way to fix this is to define the `show_category` route as an additional action in the resource:

```
resources :movies do
  post :show_category, on: :collection
end
```

Also, you seem to have a method mismatch. You list the action as POST in your routes.rb, and yet you're making a GET method. I think the problem is in your `link_to` call: instead of `method: :post`, you should write `data: { method: :post }`.

This should fix it. For more information, look at the [Rails routing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), specifically the [Adding RESTful actions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) section.

Comment: I tried this in `routes.rb` now: `Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :movies do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    root to: "movies#index"

    #get '/movies/show_category', to: 'movies#show_category', as: 'show_movies_by_category'
    get :show_category, on: :collection
 end
end
` now when I hit `localhost:3000`, I get the `Welcome to Rails` page instead of my application's home page

Comment: The file here is completely incomprehensible. Maybe link it via Pastebin or a Github gist?

Comment: You shouldn't put the whole thing in the `resources` block, just the `get :show_category, on: :collection`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

View:

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr><td>
        <%= link_to show_category, :remote => true do %> 
          Show Category
        <% end %>
      </td></tr>
    <% end %>
```

routes:

```
  get 'show_category', to: 'movies#show_category', as: 'show_category'
```

You don't need the respond_to in controller. You can remove all that.

This will invoke show_category.js.erb

Comment: When I tried your exact code, I still got the "Welcome to Rails" default page. I then changed it to `<%= link_to category, :remote => true do%>Show Category <%end%>`. Now I get my application home page all right but when I click on one of the categories, I get this error on the Rails console - `Started GET "/Romance" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-06 15:55:02 +0530
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Romance"):`

Comment: In routes you only have to replace the corresponding line, not everything..

Comment: ok. I have pasted my entire `routes.rb` here - https://pastebin.com/mKsnxkFe . I have pasted the code from movies/index.html.erb here - https://pastebin.com/34aU5xjQ And this is my movies_controller - https://pastebin.com/004xHUcq. (I know you mentioned I could remove the `respond_to` in my controller; so should I just have an empty `show_controller` function?

Comment: I made a silly mistake. I have updated index.html.erb - https://pastebin.com/34aU5xjQ Now my `_show_controller.html.erb` is getting called just fine but I had defined a `@movies_by_category` in my `movies_controller` which is not being made available in `_show_controller.html.erb`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you keep changing instead of try solutions given you won't go very far..

Comment: You should understand better how to use stackoverflow.. Perhaps hiring a professional to fix your stuff fits better for you